# Error while deploying ARM template to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have the following error when using `az cli` to deploy an ARM template to Azure:

```
Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2018-06-18T10:02:34.3290000Z' and the TokensValidFrom date for this user is '2018-08-27T08:45:47.0000000Z'
Trace ID: *********-****-****-****-************
Correlation ID: ********-****-****-****-************
Timestamp: 2018-08-29 08:31:34Z","error_codes":[50173],"timestamp":"2018-08-29 08:31:34Z","trace_id":"********-****-****-****-************","correlation_id":"********-****-****-****-************"}
```

Comment: can you try to login again using `az login`

Comment: Yeah, that does the trick

Comment: According to the error message, the token has expired.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your login (token) has *expired*. Try to **login again** using:

```
az login
```